# Waterfall plotting with Scilab

Tags: matlab, plot, scilab, waterfall

I have multiple energy spectrum result and I plotted them in the same graph as 3d(X: frequency, Y:data number, Z:energy) by using param3d1. Now I am trying make the line color change according to the Z-axis value on Scilab (like waterfall plotting on Matlab). Is there any way to do it?

I am able to change the line color to one specific color by using .foreground as shown in "graphics_entities"-help.scilab.org

and I tried to use colormap by making foreground to equal colormap but it gives error saying I can't change that children property directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might find it helpful to check out the guide on asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In particular, providing a minimal, complete example of your code showing what you have already tried would help others in answering your question.

Comment: waterfall plotting is not possible in Scilab. Only plain surface facets can have a color proportional to Z.